# Why does JQuery give different results for .text(), .html(), and .val(), when used on an empty JQuery object?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

This is really less of a practical question, and more theoretical, but it does affect some code that I am currently writing, so I'll go ahead and ask.

I'm using JQuery to parse an XML feed and build page elements, based on the returned XML elements.  The XML is converted into a JQuery object and getting to the elements is all well and good.

At one point, when I am retrieving values, I test to see if an element exists and retrieve it's contents using `.text()`.  I wanted to be careful and check to make sure that my selector had returned something before checking for the text, but noticed something funny . . . `.text()` doesn't seem to care.  If JQuery object that is returned by the selector is empty, `.text()` will return `""` when used on it.

"Pretty cool", I thought, until I realized that the behavior is different with `.html()` and `.val()` . . . `.html()` returns `null` and `.val()` returns `undefined` (in Firefox . . . in IE, they both return `undefined`).

Try it out:

```
var tempVal = $("#noWayThisIsAnElement");
window.console.log(tempVal.text());          // returns ""
window.console.log(tempVal.html());          // returns null (undefined, in IE)
window.console.log(tempVal.val());           // returns undefined
```

**So, does anyone know what the reasoning behind this is?**

The main reason that I ask is that, considering that they are looking for similar kinds of values (conceptually), you would think that the "oops, can't do that" result would be the same.

I guess I can see that `.val()` might be different than the other two, because it can return one of three data types, but even if you remove that, both `.text()` and `.html()` return strings, and those strings represent the content of the DOM node . . . you would think that they would both give a similar result when the JQuery object holds no reference to a node.

So, I guess I'll just code differently for the two situations for now, but, in the meantime, does anyone have any insight here?

---

**UPDATE**:  Kevin B brings up a good point (not sure why I didn't think of it, actually   :D   ) about `.val()` in that it is looking for the `value` attribute, which is undefined.  That's consistent with how `.attr()` behaves in this situation as well.

The difference between `.text()` and `.html()` is still open, though.   :)

Comment: the .val result makes sense because the value attribute is undefined. the .text() result makes sense because .text concatenates the text of all selected elements and returns it. Since there are no selected elements, the concatenated text is "". As far as .html, i'm unsure.

Comment: Yeah, I guess `.val()` makes makes the most sense . . . `.attr(SOME_ATTRIBUTE)` also returns `undefined`.  As for `.text()`, though, isn't `.html()` a concatination of **all** of the content of an element?

Comment: Appreciate this question. Seems `.text()` is the real weirdo.  No `.html()` is not a concatenation -- the [doc says](http://api.jquery.com/html/) "If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the **first match** will have its HTML content returned."

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone - Sorry for any confusion . . . you are right that it is not a concatenation of a group of selected elements, but it IS a concatenation of all of the elements contained within a single selected element (i.e., a concatenation of its descendants).

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the implementation :

### val()

```
val: function( value ) {
        var ret, hooks, isFunction,
            elem = this[0];

        if ( !arguments.length ) {
            if ( elem ) {
                hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

                if ( hooks && "get" in hooks && (ret = hooks.get( elem, "value" )) !== undefined ) {
                    return ret;
                }

                ret = elem.value;

                return typeof ret === "string" ?
                    // handle most common string cases
                    ret.replace(rreturn, "") :
                    // handle cases where value is null/undef or number
                    ret == null ? "" : ret;
            }

            return;
        }
```

As you see, if there is no elem (ie empty jquery object), function directly `return;` : you got an `undefined`

### text()

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    text: function( value ) {
        return jQuery.access( this, function( value ) {
            return value === undefined ?
                jQuery.text( this ) :
                this.empty().append( ( this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document ).createTextNode( value ) );
        }, null, value, arguments.length );
    },
```

`getText` is the implementation of the `jQuery.text()` function

```
getText = Sizzle.getText = function( elem ) {
    var node,
        ret = "",
        i = 0,
        nodeType = elem.nodeType;

    if ( !nodeType ) {
        // If no nodeType, this is expected to be an array
        for ( ; (node = elem[i]); i++ ) {
            // Do not traverse comment nodes
            ret += getText( node );
        }
    } else if ( nodeType === 1 || nodeType === 9 || nodeType === 11 ) {
        // Use textContent for elements
        // innerText usage removed for consistency of new lines (see #11153)
        if ( typeof elem.textContent === "string" ) {
            return elem.textContent;
        } else {
            // Traverse its children
            for ( elem = elem.firstChild; elem; elem = elem.nextSibling ) {
                ret += getText( elem );
            }
        }
    } else if ( nodeType === 3 || nodeType === 4 ) {
        return elem.nodeValue;
    }
    // Do not include comment or processing instruction nodes

    return ret;
};
```

As you can see, with an empty object, we don't enter in any condition. `ret` is initialized to "", so it returns "".

### html()

```
html: function( value ) {
return jQuery.access( this, function( value ) {
    var elem = this[0] || {},
        i = 0,
        l = this.length;

    if ( value === undefined ) {
        return elem.nodeType === 1 ?
            elem.innerHTML.replace( rinlinejQuery, "" ) :
            undefined;
    }
```

Here, you can see it returns `undefined` too. I don't know why it would return a null but you are right, I tested it on Chrome.

If others can complete this post.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that there was more to it that just how it was implemented . . . some kind of reason that they decided to not keep the behavior standard between the two calls.  It's interesting to see how different the calls are, though, given that the high-level, they are trying to retrieve fairly similar information.